# OPA Gatekeeper constraints not working only allow images from a private registry

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, open-policy-agent

So I have installed a OPA Gatekeeper in kubernetes in AWS using helm chart. I have tried v3.9.0 and v3.12.0 helm chart for gatekeeper.
Once I apply constraints template and constraint that allow only private registry images.
However when I try to apply some random image to still creates pod of it rather giving me an error.

This is my constraints-template.yaml

```
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: k8sallowedrepos
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sAllowedRepos
      validation:
        # Schema for the `parameters` field
        openAPIV3Schema:
          properties:
            repos:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8sallowedrepos

        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          container := input.review.object.spec.containers[_]
          satisfied := [good | repo = input.parameters.repos[_] ; good = contains(container.image, repo)]
          not any(satisfied)
          msg := sprintf("container <%v> has an invalid image repo <%v>, allowed repos are %v", [container.name, container.image, input.parameters.repos])
        }

        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          container := input.review.object.spec.initContainers[_]
          satisfied := [good | repo = input.parameters.repos[_] ; good = contains(container.image, repo)]
          not any(satisfied)
          msg := sprintf("container <%v> has an invalid image repo <%v>, allowed repos are %v", [container.name, container.image, input.parameters.repos])
        }
```

And this is my constraint.yaml

```
kind: K8sAllowedRepos
metadata:
  name: allow-only-private-registry
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Pod"]
  parameters:
    repos:
      - "private.example.com"
```

Testing OPA with below file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: swiss-army-knife-disallowed
spec:
  containers:
    - name: swiss-army-knife
      image: rancherlabs/swiss-army-knife:latest
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "30Mi"
```

After running below command

```
kubectl apply -f disallowed.yaml
```

It just gives me created message, I am expecting it should give me an error.

Answer (score -1):

Here must define enforcement action in the constraint file, In gatekeeper we have three types action ["info", "warn", "deny"], Now you can specify depends on your requirement

### Example:-

apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sAllowedRepos
metadata:
name: allowed-repositories
spec:
enforcementAction: warn
match:
kinds:
- apiGroups: [""]
kinds: ["Pod"]
parameters:
repos:
- ""

Comment: it doesn't work. the default enforcementAction is deny